# Can't connect to a remote database

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I attempt to connect to a remote database by command line :

```
jtodeschini@JT-laptop:~$ mysql -u root -p -h groupe-oz.com
```

Enter password:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'LCaen-656-1-31-79.w193-251.abo.wanadoo.fr' (using password: YES)

I had try with a web interface with the same user and password and it's work on my pc, but not on another.

So i didn't understand where I have a problem.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory

Comment: Where is the same error ?

Comment: When I connect by php I can connect on the remote database .

But I connect by command, It print what I have show you. 

So I realy don't understand this error...

Comment: Access is denied - what is not to understand?